# creating dummy variables for zip code and populating existing table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a too many zip codes in my data to run an analysis using this as a categorical variable, so I need to create a dummy variable. location, and group zip codes.  Currently I have a blank column labeled Location that needs to be populated. Example Follows

ID   ZIP   location

1  28201

2  28202

3  28203

4  28206

5  28207

6  38300

7  38305

8  38306

I want to do something like an IF THEN, though I am thinking of the IF THEN that is used in SAS.  Something like IF 28200< zip <29200 then Location = 1; If 38000< zip < 39000 then location= 2

ID   ZIP   location

1  28201  1

2  28202  1

3  28203  1

4  28206  1

5  28207  1

6  38300  2

7  38305  2

8  38306  2

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for CASE.  Something like

```
UPDATE table
SET location = 
    CASE
        WHEN zip > 28200 AND zip < 29200 THEN 1
        WHEN zip > 38000 AND zip < 39000 THEN 2
    END;
```

Comment: D'oh, yeah, that's exactly what I was looking for; can't believe i didn't think of that. Thanks